# Greasemonkey js going to subpage, again, again and wait

Tags: javascript, location, href

sorry for bad english and maybe newby question. 
I want to write script that makes something automatic (in web game), everything I need to is go to subpage, then next one, and other. Then script needs to wait specific time and repeat.
I'm using global variable (boolean) and if its true I'm trying to do something like that:

```
unsafeWindow.location.href = linktodo + linkequipeq + accesKey;
unsafeWindow.location.href = linktodo + linkjednoraz + accesKey;
```

Script skips first going to page. Using setTimeout doesn't helped. I'm using:

```
// @run-at document-end
```

Still not working, I tried to use addEventListener wit parametr 'load' but nothing (I think I need to "clean" eventlistener by closing the window? - tried to use removeEventListener after first function/window redirect is done, fail).

Is it possible to do this without opening and closing new tabs/popups? 
Will script like this work in inactive tab?
Can somebody post some example of doing it or tutorial I'll learn it alone?

P.s
for some explanations, those subpages will fill on some equipment, then get some cash and go quest. 
linktodo is hostname, linkequipeq is pathname, and accesKey is some secuirty builded in webpage to not doing something after reload (I get acces to it via GM using unsafeWindow).

Huh mayby somebody understand me :D

```
// @include     "site"
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// @grant       GM_getValue
// @grant       GM_setValue
// @grant       GM_deleteValue
// @grant       GM_listValues
// @grant       GM_xmlhttpRequest 
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @run-at document-end
var wypki = 0;
var cash = 0;
var czas = 0;
var autowypki = false;

var linkwypki = '?a=q';
var linksklep = '?a=town=';
var linkequipeq = '?a=equip';
var linkjednoraz = '?a=buyone';
var linkrealm;
var accesKey = unsafeWindow.accessKey;
var numbercash = document.getElementsByClassName('cash')[0].getElementsByClassName('panel');
var mynumbercash = numbercash[0];
var cash1 = (mynumbercash.innerHTML);
cash = cash1.slice(28, cash1.indexOf('PLN'));
cash = parseInt(cash.replace(/\s+/g, ''));

var linktodo = link.slice(0, link.indexOf('?a='));

function doquest() {
    'use strict';
    unsafeWindow.location.href = linktodo + linkwypki;
    setTimeout(function () {
        unsafeWindow.getElementById('start')[0].click();
    }, 2000);

}
function zlomek() {
    'use strict';

    if (cash < 20000) {
        unsafeWindow.location.href = linktodo + linksklep + accesKey;
    }
}
function jednoraz() {
    'use strict';
    if (autowypki === true && cash > 20000) {
        unsafeWindow.location.href = linktodo + linkjednoraz + accesKey;
    }
}
function equip() {
    'use strict';
    unsafeWindow.location.href = linktodo + linkequipeq + accesKey;
}
/* --- Main ----*/
function autoQuest() {
    'use strict';
    autowypki = true;
    equip();
    setTimeout(jednoraz(),5000);
}
/* --- Main ----*/

if (a === linkwypki) {
    var przyciskwypki = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].getElementsByTagName('div')[13];
    przyciskwypki.innerHTML =  przyciskwypki.innerHTML + '<input class="button" type="button" style="height: 20px; width: 110px;" id="autowypki"  value=" Robimy wypki"  />';
}
document.getElementById("autowypki").addEventListener("click", autoQuest, false);
```

Comment: You'll need to show a little more of the code, but as you posted it, there's no surprise you're getting the behaviour you observe.

Comment: Added, thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

Greasemonkey scripts are exactly like normal scripts, they don't run unless the page is loaded

On any page that this script is injected loaded, this script will add a click event listener to the element with `ID='autowypki'`

when that event is fired, the script will set the page to `linktodo + linkequipeq + accesKey` in function `equip`

and that's all this script will ever do

there's nowhere that invokes functions `doquest` and `zlomak`, so they're just along for the ride in this script

function `jednoraz` is set to be called after a timeout of 5 seconds, but by then `equip` has loaded a new page, so, `jednoraz` wont actually be called as the page it was on is no longer loaded

however, if the same click event is fired in the page that `equip` loads, then **perhaps** `jednoraz` will be called - and then the page `linktodo + linkjednoraz + accesKey` will be loaded ... I say perhaps, because I'm not 100% sure what function `equip` will do if it's effectively setting the page to the current page - i.e. if that causes a page load, then `jednoraz` wont be called because the timeout will probably never fire as the page has reloaded

Comment: I know how it works and why it fires (cuz page reload everytime). And i didn't (yet) try to call other functions until, I'll be sure the first ones works. 
Most functions needs to go subpage cuz:
`www.page.com/?a=eq` - equips items
`www.page.com/?a=buyone` - buys some item

I need to call them one by one.
Trying to call other function (new url so reload) after page is fully loaded not works so how to do this in other way?

Comment: After page is fully loaded i tryied to use `function equip() {
    'use strict';
    unsafeWindow.location.href = linktodo + linkequipeq + accesKey;
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", jednoraz());
}`